# Insert query won't return on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, bulkinsert

In first place, sorry for my bad English.

I had a rails 2.3.1 project and i'm updating it to version 5.2.1. On this project, i have a delayed_job that inserts multiple lines on a database table. The code that i'm using to insert is:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
INSERT INTO <Table_Name> (id, col2, col3, col4...) 
VALUES ((select coalesce(max(id),0)+1 from <Same_Table_Name>), val2, val3, val4...);...")
```

On rails 2.3.1, it was working fine, i could execute 20000 inserts without problems, but in rails 5.2.1, if the query has more than about 1500 inserts, the rows are inserted on the table, but the query won't end, won't return.

If i remove the ids and the coalesces from the query, leaving it to the Auto Increment, it sometimes works and sometimes crashes because of other inserts on the project that don't update the Auto Increment's index. And if i execute the query directly from the Postgres Query Tool it works fine.

I have also already tried to use ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query but the limit of inserts is even smaller.